# Getting data from vector in an std::map

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to write a class that renders models from .3ds files and I'm running into a really annoying issue. I have a map mapping from integers to vectors of doubles

```
map<int, vector<double> >
```

that I am using to map the vertices which have different material properties. After that I try to iterate through all of the keys and have OpenGL render them like so:

```
glPushMatrix();
glPushClientAttrib(GL_CLIENT_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

for(map<int, vector<double> >::iterator iter = myMaterialVertices.begin(); iter != myMaterialVertices.end(); iter++)
{
    vector<double> test = iter->second;
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_DOUBLE, 0, test.data());
    //get the texture coords here
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, iter->second.size() / 3);
}

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glPopClientAttrib();
glPopMatrix();
```

Unfortunately this gives me an error on the glDrawArrays call every single time telling me that I am trying to read address 0. I interpreted this to mean there was a null pointer issue, so I put in the test vector to make sure the data was there. The vector gets loaded correctly but still gives the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the vector/map structure and not glDrawArrays? Try calculating the size in a separate statement and see which line throws the error.

Comment: I tried just drawing one triangle (3 vertices) and the problem still persisted.

Comment: You're making a completely useless and expensive *copy* of each vector. I would strongly recommend fixing that.

Comment: Are you sure the call to `glVertexPointer` succeeded. If in doubt, try logging. `glGetLastError` is your friend.

Comment: I got it, this is pretty embarrassing. If you enable the texture pointer and don't specify it then it is null. Ugh I shouldn't be programming and watching football at the same time.

Comment: About what Kerrek SB said. You should write this either `vector<double> &test = iter->second;` or just use `iter->second.data()` in the glVertexPointer call.

Comment: @Pat: Write that as an answer.

Comment: I'll put up the answer. Also the test vector was just that, a test to see if the data was there. Needless to say that's not how its actually being done now that the problem is fixed. Thanks though for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it was suggested in the comments I will put up an answer. The call to

```
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

causes OpenGL to expect a pointer to an array of texture coordinates. When none was specified it threw a null pointer exception (attempt to read 0x00000000). The lesson here being don't enable client states unless you plan on defining the appropriate pointer.